# What does the "null" mean in "null hypothesis" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does the "null" mean in "null hypothesis" mean?  Null in general means none, nothing, empty, zero.  What does that mean in the context of "null hypothesis"?

Comment: I think it would be a nice courtesy if you'd at least take the time to explain what a null hypothesis is. You may get more answers, and you may get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The null hypothesis" is used in statistics. The idea here is that an experiment that is done using two groups of people will show the same results for each group. For example, if you predict men are more careless than women, the ***experimental hypothesis*** would be that men will be significantly more careless than women, whereas the ***null hypothesis*** would be there is no significant difference in carelessness between men and women.